# How to query the latest table using Standard Query

Tags: google-bigquery

In Legacy SQL, I found this syntax very useful to query the latest table from the set of tables with Date Suffix.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
TABLE_QUERY([project_id:dataset], 
  'table_id = (SELECT MAX(table_id) 
               FROM [project_id:dataset.__TABLES__]  
               WHERE table_id CONTAINS "tablename_2016")
  ')
```

so, If I have set of tables such as `tablename_20161205, tablename_20161206, tablename_20161219`, the query will find the latest table which is tablename_20161219 in this case and I don't need to look through all tables and specify the latest one.

How do I achieve this in Standard SQL? 
Thx so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables#when_to_use_wildcard_tables) (potentially with a filter to restrict the initial search). For example,

```
WITH RecentTables AS (
  SELECT *, _TABLE_SUFFIX
  FROM `project_id.dataset.*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= "tablename_2016"
),
LatestTable AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM RecentTables
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = (SELECT MAX(_TABLE_SUFFIX) FROM RecentTables)
)
SELECT *
FROM LatestTable;
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much. Based on your answer, I have a simpler solution, `With LatestTable AS ( Select Max(_table_Suffix) as TableName From \`project_id.dataset.*\`  Where regexp_contains(_Table_Suffix, "tablename_2016")      SELECT * FROM \`project_id.dataset.*\` WHERE _Table_Suffix = (Select TableName from LatestTable)`..   Thank you again for your advice.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM `project_id.dataset.*` 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = (
  SELECT table_id 
  FROM `project_id.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__` 
  ORDER BY table_id DESC 
  LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: I like your answer. It is however worth noting that this will read _all_ the tables in `dataset`, whereas when you use `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'table_name'` you only read a single table. While your answer is great and works better than the accepted, there is still room for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

To look it better, My query in Standard SQL Will be,

```
With LatestTable AS 
( 
  Select Max(_table_Suffix) as LatestTableName 
  From `project_id.dataset.*` 
  Where regexp_contains(_Table_Suffix, "tablename_2016") 
)

SELECT * 
FROM `project_id.dataset.*` 
WHERE _Table_Suffix = (Select LatestTableName from LatestTable)
```